# Restrict Characters using regex matches in java

Tags: java, regex

Basically i have a java String which i want to restrict all the characters other than this regex code

```
String UcharSet = "^[a-zA-Z0-9-~!@#().]+";
if("hello.hi".matches(UcharSet)){
        UNotAllowedCharEC = "0x00000030";
}
```

now the problem is that my if statement always gets to execute although i have my regex to allow `.` so i really appreciate  if somebody tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. `"hello.hi".matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9-~!@#().]+")` returns `true`, and `"hello$hi".matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9-~!@#().]+")` returns `false`. --- FYI: The leading `^` is redundant when using `matches()`.

Comment: then it is not suppose to input `0x00000030` to `UNotAllowedCharEC` but here i am getting the `UNotAllowedCharEC value to be 0x00000030`

Comment: Can't reproduce either.

Comment: @jacky No idea what that means. If you don't want to assign the string literal `"0x00000030"` to `UNotAllowedCharEC`, then don't write an assignment statement that does. The code you show *will* have `matches()` return true, **opposite of what you say**, so the `if` block *will* execute, as it should, and the assignment statement *will* do what you told it to do.

Comment: i just want to assign `0x00000030 to UNotAllowedCharEC` if the string contains characters not allowed, can you tell me how to get this job done

Comment: Aren't you looking for a naegated character class? `String UcharSet = "[^-a-zA-Z0-9~!@#().]+";`. BTW, `hello.hi` is matched with `[a-zA-Z0-9-~!@#().]+`, so there is no surprise here.

Answer (score 0):

first i create a boolean which is equal to `"hi+hello".matches(UcharSet)` and i needed to create an if statement and see if it returned true or false:

```
boolean UMORN = "hi+hello".matches(UcharSet);
if(UMORN != true)
    UNotAllowedCharEC = "0x00000030";
```